# Raspberry Pi kiosk mode

Tags: gui

I would like to have a Raspberry PI with some sort of kiosk-mode. Basically I want it to run a single application and I am trying to determine what is the smallest build that can do that.

I haven't built the application yet so I am open to any suggestions. The application must have a GUI that's not ASCII based.

It seems that any x server takes a lot of space and installs a lot of crapware.

Any suggestions?

Comment: N.b. *"any x server takes a lot of space and installs a lot of crapware"* -> You've mistaken the X server for the DE (desktop environment).  X alone does not include anything but itself (you get a black screen and a mouse pointer) and is pretty much the minimum requirement for providing a GUI environment.  One instance requires ~50 MB RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and clarification. I was indeed confusing X with DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway you need any graphical server. X server itself is not so cumbersome as you might think. All detailed instructions you may find in this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9215/how-to-set-up-kiosk-mode-in-raspbian), mentioned by @goldilocks

Also look at [RetroPie Project](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/) as example, which is based on Raspbian and launches [EmulationStation](http://emulationstation.org/index.html) as kiosk app