# Auto startup of the Midori web browser is not working on Raspberry pi

Tags: linux

I am trying to start the [Midori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_%28web_browser%29) web browser on Raspberry Pi, on boot. These are the steps I've followed so far:

1. I have edited the `.bashrc` file from the root folder using this command:

   ```
   sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
   ```
2. Added the following line at the end of the file.

   ```
   midori -e Fullscreen -a http://www.google.com
   ```
3. I restarted Raspberry Pi:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

It does not open the browser, on boot. However, if I manually click on Terminal, it opens the browser.

I have added the below lines in the autostartup file.

```
# Auto run the browser
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@midori -e Fullscreen -a http://google.
```

But it did not open the browser with this code when I restarted the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: As you are booting into the GUI bash is not started so .bashrc is not used. When you open a terminal a new bash shell is started and .bashrc is run. What OS are you using?

Comment: Do you want it to go straight to the browser without anyone logging in, or do you want the browser to start when a user logs in?

Comment: I want it to directly go the browser with out log in.

Comment: I am using Raspbian Debian Wheezy  Kernel version:3.12 . And also I have updated Raspberry pi by using the command.  sudo apt-get update

Comment: What you want is called a **kiosk**.  That's possible, but a little complicated to set up: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9692/5538

Answer (score 7):

I got the solution. In new versions it is not supported in this autostart file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

I changed the code to the below autostart file.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice  [autostart guide](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/gui/auto-run-browser-on-startup) that explains how to setup the

/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

file to autostart Midori when the Pi boots into X.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: I have folled the steps given in autostart guide

Comment: I have folled the steps given in autostart guide. But this time it is not opening the browser even if I run the terminal

Answer (score 0):

move to directory

```
cd /home/pi/.config/autostart/
```

create new file midori.desktop

```
sudo nano midori.desktop
```

and add this lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=midori
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
X-GNOME-FullName=midori
Exec=midori -e Fullscreen -a http://www.google.com
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the mentioned methods and they did not work for me.
It is noteworthy that epiphany outperforms midori in many aspects. To use epiphany, I tried this:

nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

the content of this file is like this:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@sh ${HOME}/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autokey.sh
```

So, in order to ask epiphany to open on boot just add this line to the end of this file.

epiphany --display=:0 http://google.com

To prevent Raspberry to go on screen saver mode, add the following line in 
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
under [SeatDefaults] section.
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms

That's all.